# Check File Size while writing in loop

Tags: c#, filesize

I am looping through files in a directory and writing the file names into an output file using StreamWriter.
The file can not grow larger than 60K
What is the best way to check this?
Now, I create a new FileInfo variable in each loop (as in code below) and check its Length property, like in this code:

```
foreach (var file in directories)
{
    if (file.FullName.Contains("\\BAK\\")) continue;
    myStream.WriteLine(file.FullName);
    counter += 1;
    FileInfo myPaths = new FileInfo(outFile);
    if (myPaths.Length >= 60000)
    {
        //Do Procedure
    }
}
```

I was thinking, maybe it would be quicker and simpler to just count the Length of each string before writing. I.e.,

```
fileSz += file.FullName.Length
if (fileSz >= 60000) // do procedure
```

Or maybe there is another option?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you constructed the `StreamWriter` by passing a path you can use `myStream.BaseStream.Length` to determine the file's size. If you constructed the `StreamWriter` by passing a stream to it, then you already have access to that stream's `Length` property. :) No need for the `FileInfo` or calculating the length when you can query the stream to find out. Keep it simple. :)

If later you decide you need to change your output file from UTF-16 TO UTF-8 (or another encoding), the `Length` property still works fine.

Comment: Hi Curt. That's exactly what I was looking for. I knew there had to be a way to get it without going to the FileInfo.
Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 2):

In general, the size of a C# string in bytes is *approximately* `2n + 20` where `n` is the length of the string. You could use this to approximate, but remember to include the newline characters of `WriteLine` in your estimate.

```
fileSz += (2 * file.FullName.Length + 20 + Environment.NewLine.Length);
if (fizeSz <= 59500 * 1024) ... // Keep it under 59.5k to be safe, also 1024 bytes per kb
```

Comment: Hi Haney. Thanks for this valuable info. Is this indeed more efficient than reinstating the FileInfo variable during each loop?

Comment: It would definitely be more efficient due to not reading file info from the drive.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just retrieve the directory as a DirectoryInfo object and then call  GetfileSystemInfos method which will natively return the FileSystemInfo you need without having to create another variable. Get FileSystemINfos also lets you natively filter out the bak files

```
var files = dir.GetFileSystemInfos("*.txt")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383457.aspx

Comment: Hi Bill. Thanks for your response. I don't fully understand it though. I do understand that it will allow me to natively exclude the BAK directory which is great. But how does this help me check the size of the file that I am consistently writing to throughout the loop? If I received the fileInfo before the loop, how is it getting updated during the loop?

Comment: Hi Bill, actually, I dont understand how the "GetFileSystemInfos" function excludes folders. What is that Searchstring that you entered?

Comment: Actually I was wrong, I thought GetFileSystemInfos supported old dos style search filters but it does not, it only supports * and ?. So if you knew you were only searching for, say, txt files it could work but it's not going to natively work to just "get me all files that don't end in bak"

Answer (score 1):

Use `Length` property of `myStream`.